# Apache File component - Throw error if file is not present

Tags: file-io, apache-camel

Below code reads the content of the file if the file is present but if the file is not present then it just gets stuck in that line.

How can I throw an error or come out "file://" statement if the mentioned file (myFile.txt in the example below) is not present in the directory?

```
from("file://input?fileName=myfile.txt&delete=true")
            .log("${body}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats not how the file consumer works, or the idea of Camel routes. Its to be event driven, so if a file is dropped in the input directory with the name `myfile.txt` then Camel reacts. Until then it waits.

If you want to check for the existence of a file, you can use Java's `java.io.File` API for this.

The file consumer can be configured however to send an empty message if there was no file, but then it will keep doing this. See the docs https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html